# pdfstring for math symbols

Tags: sectioning, hyperref

I need to generate bookmarks and use math symbols in my section titles. I know I need to use `\texorpdfstring{}{}` command. My question is, what are the math symbols for the pdfstrings? Are there any references, handbooks or links I can look them up? For example, this is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction to variance \texorpdfstring{\sigma^{2}}{???}}

\section{Introduction to finite mean \texorpdfstring{\mu=\sum_{i}x_{i}}{???}}


\end{document}
```

In this code, I don't know what the pdfstrings for square and sum symbols are.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Searching "tex to unicode" shows this which gives reasonable output for your examples: https://www.unicodeit.net/. It gives σ² and μ=∑ᵢxᵢ. Also note you are missing `$`'s in your code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic bookmark commands are in `puenc.def` such as `\texttwosuperior` (²). The greek block is in an extra file `puenc-greek.def` which will be `\input` into `puenc.def` if `\textBeta` is defined:

```
% puenc.def line 611--613
\ifx\textBeta\@undefined \else
\input{puenc-greek.def}
\fi
```

In your case you need `\mu` (μ) and `\sigma` (σ), so it is necessary to predefine `\textBeta` to use the greek block:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\def\textBeta{}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction to variance \texorpdfstring{$\sigma^{2}$}{\textsigma\texttwosuperior}}

\section{Introduction to finite mean \texorpdfstring{$\mu=\sum_{i}x_{i}$}{\textmu\ = \textsum\textiinferior x\textiinferior}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

PS:

1. It is recommended to use `bookmark` package since it usually needs only one LaTeX run and can provide more control over the bookmark appearance (like color, font).
2. Use `kpsewhich` to find the file location. For example, on mac, I can directly run `open $(kpsewhich puenc.def)` or `` open `kpsewhich puenc.def` `` in the terminal to open `puenc.def`.